# how to conditionally redirect bash script output

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I want to control the logging from a bash script. I'm newish to scripting and have inherited a script with this:

```
LOG_STDOUT=/tmp/stdout.$$
LOG_STDERR=/tmp/stderr.$$
exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2
exec 1>${LOG_STDOUT}
exec 2>${LOG_STDERR}
set -x
echo $0 $SCRIPTREV starting $(date) >&3
...
echo ERRORMESS > &4
```

The overall redirection can of course controlled by putting the execs in a conditional, but I don't know how to manage the >&3 and >&4 redirection.

What's a good way to handle this, so the log files usually collect all the output from -x, but optionally allowing me to have all output go to console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid changing the exec statements by working with the output variables:

```
[ $STD -eq 1 ] && LOG_STDOUT=/dev/stdout || LOG_STDOUT=/tmp/stdout.$$
[ $STD -eq 1 ] && LOG_STDOUT=/dev/stderr || LOG_STDERR=/tmp/stderr.$$
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good suggestion putnamhill.

Actually I've realized it's a dumb question. All I need to do it put the conditional around the third and fourth exec statements only (I'd had the conditional around all the execs). That way, the >&3 and >&4 are redirected to &1 and &2 so are not a problem.

I.e this is my way of avoiding the issue:

```
LOG_STDOUT=/tmp/stdout.$$
LOG_STDERR=/tmp/stderr.$$
exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2

if [[ $mydebug ]]; then
    echo NOT REDIRECTING
else
    exec 1>${LOG_STDOUT}
    exec 2>${LOG_STDERR}
fi
```